# Parse open source server on AWS ClientKeys

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, parse-server

I am switching a app over to AWS open source parse server but I am having problems with this code.

```
 [Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration> configuration) {
    configuration.applicationId = @"App ID";
       configuration.clientKey = @"";
    configuration.server = @"my server URL";
  }]];
```

I do not have a Client key and it is crashing without one. If any one could help that would be great.

Comment: what server url did you use for AWS?

Comment: There is a https: URL with /parse at the end

Comment: Hm... I have tried that, but with no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to not crash by putting some thing in for the `clientKey` so it was not `null`. It should run fine because the new parse server does not need a clientKey to run.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Migrating an Existing Parse App](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Migrating-an-Existing-Parse-App), you can get the Client Key from Security & Keys section of App Settings in your [Parse.com Dashboard](https://dashboard.parse.com/).

Comment: I am trying to connect my app on Xcode to the AWS server that works and has keys. I need a way to get the servers data in my DB

Answer (score 0):

The Parse Server DOES need a clientKey to run correctly.
And it does need the one that you can get from App Settings > Security Keys > Client Key, in your Parse.com dashboard.